# Java compilation error - continue cannot be used outside of a loop

Tags: java, loops

Getting an error where the Eclipse Java IDE is giving me trouble with continue statements:

```
    double sum = 0.0;  
    double avg = 0.0;
    for (i=0 ; i<daRun1.length ; i++);
    {
        if(daRun1[i] == max || daRun1[i] == min)
            {
            continue; //<-- **this is where the error is showing (underlined in red in eclipse)**
            }
        sum += daRun1[i];
    }
    avg = sum / (daRun1.length-2);

    System.out.println("The average score is: " + avg);
```

What's wrong with my code? This exact if loop was used in a demonstration and there were no problems.

Comment: I doubt that the Java Runtime will show a different behaviour. :-)

Comment: @AndyTurner Not lying, but maybe sometimes not to the point too. (Not related here)

Comment: Your brace placement makes this hard to read.  If you put opening braces on the same line as for and if you wouldn't make this mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `continue` is not in the for loop.

You end the loop with the semi-colon here:

```
for (i=0 ; i<daRun1.length ; i++);
```

Remove the semi-colon, and it shall work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon after the for statement.

Answer (score 1):

See the compilation error shown by Eclipse [ try hover over the red underline]

> continue cannot be used outside of a loop

Eclipse is a powerful tool and shows compilation errors while we code.

As mentioned in the error it self : `continue` is being used outside the loop, i.e. body of loop has already ended and after that continue is being used. When you see your code you find exact same thing, you can see the semicolons `;` just after the for loop.

Convert

```
for ( i=0 ;  i < daRun1.length ; i ++ );
```

to

```
for (i=0 ; i<daRun1.length ; i++)
```

And `continue` will no longer show compilation error.